# Rhino Mock, get TempData after RedirectToRoute

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, rhino-mocks, rhino-mocks-3.5

How to getting TempData after RedirectToAction in Rhino Mock test?

Code

```
public ActionResult Action1() {
    TempData["Foo"] = "Bar";
    return RedirectToAction("Action2");
}
public ActionResult Action2() {
    return View();
}
```

Test

```
 using (var controller = new TestController(x => x.Register(service))){
    var result = (RedirectToRouteResult)controller.Action1();

    // How to get TempData value there ?!
 }
```

Comment: I assume it's an MVC controller? Is it not simply a case of accessing the `TempData` property and checking?

Comment: Yes, sure. I thinking, controller Tempdata must  been mocked before I can work with test NUnit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties and methods of base classes are part of your derived class, and are therefore part of the system under test (SUT). You only need to mock *dependencies* of the system under test - other classes that the system under test interacts with.

In this situation, you don't need a mock, because `TempData` is a property of `ControllerBase`, which your controller is derived from:

```
using (var controller = new TestController(x => x.Register(service)))
{
    var result = (RedirectToRouteResult)controller.Action1();
    Assert.AreEqual("Bar", controller.TempData["Foo"]);
}
```